# Logout button in XFCE can't be blocked

Tags: debian, xfce

### Hi

Is there any way how to **disable logout button in XFCE logout menu**? I know how to disable shutdown, restart or hibernation but no luck with logout.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try openboxlogout you can customize it according to your like.
or
change the logout to do something else eg shutdown
change in /usr/share/applications/xfce4-session-logout.desktop:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0  
Type=Application  
Exec=/usr/bin/xfce4-session-shutdown.sh  
Icon=system-log-out  
StartupNotify=false  
Terminal=false  
Categories=System;X-XFCE;X-Xfce-Toplevel;  
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;  
Name=Log Out
```

and using this shutdown script /usr/bin/xfce4-session-shutdown.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh     
sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now $*
```

Comment: Actually, I did something you've described. I point Exec option to script telling user that logging out is disabled. But it's really not a solution, it's a walk around. Thanks anyway...

Comment: I try this solution but it isnt exact solution for this question, I need exact solution for this topic, I want to know how to disable log out button