# Logout button in Login DIalog XFCE4 can't be disabled

Tags: linux

I have a problem with Log Out button in log out dialog in xfce4, actually I know how should be disable restart, shutdown and remove Save Session. but I cant disable the log out button.

I do some search on the internet and use this link. but I couldnt disable that button.

[How to disable Save Session](https://askubuntu.com/a/1201304)

[How to change action of Log Out Button to shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754147/4576249)

[Kiosk Documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/advanced#kiosk_mode)

[Repo on github](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-session)

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Explain how you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754147/4576249 and it did not help.

Comment: @stark actually i want to change action or remove log out button in log out dialog not create a application with name Log out that shutdown or reboot system

Comment: Why not change it to an application that pops up a dialog box which says "Logout function disabled"?